# Tumblr new audio player in custom theme

Tags: audio, tumblr

I'm trying to help my daughter-in-law with her Tumblr blog. When she tries to add an audio link she gets the following...

> You are using a custom theme that doesn't include the code for Tumblr's new audio player. 
>   You can either switch to a preset theme or add the new audio code to your custom theme's HTML (for advanced users).

I have created a blog with a preset theme and and compared the code to hers and see that it is very much different. So much so that I am not sure what to change.

I was able to get the above message to go away by replacing the block:Audio block in the div class="post" div with the following...

```
{block:Audio}
   <section class="top audio">
   {AudioPlayerBlack}
   </section>
{/block:Audio}
```

There is a lot of other audio references in the preset theme, but I am not sure where to put it or what is needed.

Is there more I need to do. I am waiting for her to test it, but in the mean time can someone point me to instructions of the proper way to do this, or help me out otherwise?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

I was able to to test it and it works fine.

For anyone with the same problem, you can simply copy the block:audio code in my question and replace the block:audio code in your custom themed blog.

John